# How to format time string in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetime-format

I am fetching time from the database to my app.
I want to fetch time from this `2018-10-17 14:52:52` format to this `2:52 PM, 17 Oct` format.

How can I format the time without using the 'moment' library?

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = new Date('2018-10-17 14:52:52');

const output = input.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeStyle: 'short'}) + ', ' + input.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {day: 'numeric'}) + ' ' + input.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: 'short'});

console.log(output); // 2:52 PM, 17 Oct
```

Comment: AFAIK this won't work in production but in development. You need a 3rd party library or the built-in date formatting libraries of iOS or Android operating systems.

Comment: @aytek, Is moment.js library is necessary for this?

Comment: @AfifaKhan yes that's commonly used. But keep in mind that if your app supports multiple languages you need to include those locales in your project.